# How is it possible to restore a SQL Server 2008 R2 database to SQL Server 2008?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I need to restore backup taken from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2008 Express edition. Is it possible?

Error encountered while restoring

[image]

Comment: how ? pls help.

Comment: first I back-up the database from sql r2 2008 server then when I'm restoring it to my sql 2008 express this error I encountered .. "Specified cast not valid(sqlmanagerui)"

Comment: No, you can't restore a 2008 R2 backup onto 2008. This has been asked and answered dozens and dozens of times. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857924/restore-sql-2008-db-r2-to-sql2008-no-r2

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you wouldn't expect binary file (backup file) from a newer version of the product to be supported on an older version of the product.

Are you dealing with just different levels of the SQL Server 2008 R2 product and have a typo in your question?  Or are you trying to use a backup from the newer SQL Server 2008 R2 on an older version o the product SQL Server 2008 Express?

Comment: Im trying from the newer SQL 2008 R2 to an older version sql 2008

Comment: @Rodz Why? Both are no longer supported.

Comment: because our clients is not yet upgrading their sql server.

Comment: @Rodz Do your clients know that SQL Server 2008 & 2008 R2 have been out of support for some time now?

Comment: ok thanks for the advise :)